# I have a list of STL vectors and I want to sort them by the first element of each vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, vector, stl

I have a list of vectors from STL. They have different lengths and I want to sort them by the first element of each vector. For example, I have the vectors: 4 **4** 5 6 10, 1 **8**, 2 **2** 3 and 3 **1** 7 9. The first number is the size of each vector and it is followed by the vector's elements. I want to display the vectors in a file, sorted by the first element. In this example, my vectors should display in this order: 3 **1** 7 9, 2 **2** 3, 4 **4** 5 6 10 and 1 **8**.

Here is my code:

```
ofstream fout ("retele.out");
fout << T << '\n';
for (i=1; i<=T; i++)
{
    fout << sol[i].size() << ' ';
    sort(sol[i].begin(),sol[i].end());
    for (j=0; j<sol[i].size(); j++)
        fout << sol[i][j] << ' ';
    fout << '\n';
}
fout.close();
```

"T" is the number of vectors. The "sort" function is for sorting each vector, and I also need an another sort for sorting the vectors as I just described.

Comment: Can you add the declaration of the variable `sol` to this example?

Comment: Maybe `sort(sol.begin(), sol.end())`?

Comment: Here are the declarations:

unsigned int i, j;
vector <unsigned int> sol[50001];
unsigned int T;

Comment: `vector <unsigned int> sol[50001]`   Did you suppose to create a cstyle array containing 50001 vectors?

Comment: Are you storing the size of the vector as the vector's first element? If so, why?

Comment: Also, you have an array, not a list.

Comment: @TudorGălățan To have a `std::list` of `std::vector` you should declare it as `list<vector<unsigned int>> sol`.

Comment: @molbdnilo, No, the first element of each vector is the second element on my example. The first is the size of the vector.

Comment: I just want to know how to sort the vectors by the first element of each one before displaying them in the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A small clarification for other answers: the `std::vector<T>` already has `operator<` with exactly the same behavior as you described ([cplusplus description](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operators/)).

> ```
> template < class T, class Alloc >
> bool operator < (const vector<T, Alloc>& lhs, const vector<T, Alloc>& rhs);
> ```

Description:

> The less-than comparison (operator<) behaves as if using algorithm lexicographical_compare, which compares the elements sequentially using operator< in a reciprocal manner (i.e., checking both a < b and b < a) and stopping at the first occurrence.

So, you can just write

```
sort(sol.begin(), sol.end());
```

*UP*: It's written in the comments that you have an array of `std::vector`, not `std::list<std::vector>`. The array has no methods `begin()` and `end()`, so this exact code will not work. The solution is

```
sort(sol, sol + SIZE);
```

where `SIZE` is size of the part of the array you want to sort.

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't work. This is the error: "request for member 'begin' in 'sol', which is of non-class type 'std::vector<unsigned int> [50001]'".

Comment: Or even better : `sort(std::begin(sol), std::end(sol))`.

Answer (score 0):

Answer based on this [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/sort/):

You can create compare method like this:

```
bool compare_vec (const std::vector<int>& first, const std::vector<int>& second)
{
  return first[1]<second[1];
}
```

and call:

```
sol.sort(compare_vec);
```

Comment: An error occures: "request for member 'sort' in 'sol', which is of non-class type 'std::vector<unsigned int> [50001]'".

Answer (score 0):

Check out [**this**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) post.

```
bool myfunction (vector<int> i,vector<int> j) { return (i[0]<j[0]);}
struct myclass {
  bool operator() (vector<int> i,vector<int> j) { return (i[0]<j[0]);}
} myobject;


...
ofstream fout ("retele.out");
fout << T << '\n';
for (i=1; i<=T; i++)
{
    fout << sol[i].size() << ' ';
    sort(sol[i].begin(),sol[i].end(), myfunction);
    for (j=0; j<sol[i].size(); j++)
        fout << sol[i][j] << ' ';
    fout << '\n';
}
fout.close();
```

You have to implement your own **comparator**, which will be used later to sort your list of `vectors`.

Comment: this is gonna be an expensive comparison/sort, I would suggest you accept const-refs to the vectors in your 'myfunction'

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this algorithm:

```
// sort algorithm example
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::sort
#include <vector>       // std::vector

 bool myfunction (int i,int j) { return (i<j); }

struct myclass {
bool operator() (int i,int j) { return (i<j);}
} myobject;

 int main () {
 int myints[] = {32,71,12,45,26,80,53,33};
    std::vector<int> myvector (myints, myints+8);               // 32 71 12 45 26 80 53 33

  // using default comparison (operator <):
   std::sort (myvector.begin(), myvector.begin()+4);           //(12 32 45 71)26 80 53 33

         // using function as comp
    std::sort (myvector.begin()+4, myvector.end(), myfunction); // 12 32 45 71(26 33 53 80)

    // using object as comp
      std::sort (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), myobject);     //(12 26 32 33 45 53 71 80)

    // print out content:
     std::cout << "myvector contains:";
      for (std::vector<int>::iterator it=myvector.begin(); it!=myvector.end(); ++it)
      std::cout << ' ' << *it;
     std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The STL function `std::sort` contains an optional predicate.
In this case, I guess you would like to write you sort like:

```
std::sort(sol.begin(), sol.end(), [](const std::vector<int> &lhs, const std::vector<int> &rhs) { return lhs.front() < rhs.front(); });
```

Note that this code will crash if the list contains empty vectors.

If sol ain't an `std::list`, though a c-style array `std::vector<int> v[50001]` like indicated in the comments. One should rewrite this to:

```
std::sort(sol[0], sol[nofElementsFilledIn], [](const std::vector<int> &lhs, const std::vector<int> &rhs) { return lhs.front() < rhs.front(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
std::sort(MyVector.begin(), MyVector.end(), [](auto a, auto b) { return a.front() < b.front(); } );
```

I hope this can sort your vector